# 'run an errand' - what does 'run' mean?

Tags: expressions

a. He **did** an errand for his mother. 
b. He **ran** an errand for his mother.

I'm not a native english speaker. This expression 'do an errand' is easy for me to understand. We also have this expression 'do an errand' in our tongue. But in 'run an errand' I don't know what does 'run' mean. 
I understand what 'run' means in these sentence:

Can you **run** as fast as Mike? 
I **ran** to meet her.

But when natives use 'run an errand'... What nuance of meaning of the word 'run' is here? 
So, Does 'run an errand' mean 'He runs to do an errand'? If I'm walking to do an errand, it is not run an errand but do an errand? I'm confused. T.T (Oh! she is running in the picture)

[image]

Comment: The word "run" is [notorious for having many meanings](http://www.npr.org/2011/05/30/136796448/has-run-run-amok-it-has-645-meanings-so-far)

Comment: There are some words in English that are used in a multitude of ways in idioms. See the comment from @sumelic above. Mr Winchester's wonderful piece on the verb _run_ from the N.Y Times is **[here.](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/05/29/opinion/29winchester.html)**

Comment: To be clear, the physical act of running has nothing to do with the idiom _run an errand._ You could just as well crawl, skip, or pilot a helicopter in the course of completing the errand. _Run_ here means _perform._

Comment: In fact, I'm not certain I would use "do" for errands outside the house (as they typically are...)

Comment: @sumelic - I’ve run into that column before, I think.

Comment: I think run is supposed to imply that the doer is in a hurry.

Comment: I disagree about the errand being urgent or being done in a hurry.  I run errands all the time, in my parlance, and all I mean is that I'm performing them.

Comment: I would read it in the same way I understand _run a computer program_.

Answer (score 8):

"Run an errand" is an idiom. Its meaning is not built up in a natural way from the meanings of its parts. I can think of no other expression where "run" essentially just means "do", but it does here.

I think LawrenceC's answer gives a good explanation of how it makes sense for this particular idiom to have evolved.

Comment: Indeed, NOAD lists _run an errand_ as an idiom under the word _run_, as opposed to listing a definition where run generally means “perform”.

Comment: I do think "run an errand" implies that you are going somewhere else to do the errand. I wouldn't use this idiom to describe a task I have to do at my current location.

Comment: @DavidZ Doesn't *errand* itself imply that the task requires departing from where one is right now?

Comment: "I can think of no other expression where "run" essentially just means "do", but it does here." My computer runs programs all the time.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie Yes, it does, though I would say not as strongly as when paired with "run".

Comment: @eyeballfrog What about *running interference*?

Answer (score 7):

*Run* has a lot of meanings.  One of those in the form of *run to X* means to go somewhere with the intent of returning quickly.  For example:

> I'm going to run to the store and get grapes.

You intend to go to the store just to buy grapes and come back.  You aren't intending to stay at the store and browse for additional things to shop, talk to people, etc.

While an errand is usually something you do and not a place, the word *errand* typically implies you have to travel to places such as stores, etc.  So you never say *run to some errands* but merely *run some errands.*

Comment: And to add to this:  you wouldn't mean you're physically running to the store.  Here, *run* implies that the errand is quick.  Consider:  "I want to make some oatmeal this morning, but we're out of milk.  Do you mind running to the store to get some?*

Answer (score 6):

Simply put, *ran an errand* means the same as *did an errand*. Here, *run* is not literal. *Run* has [many meanings](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/run?s=t), which include *perform, complete, accomplish*. Furthermore, you could drive or walk to your destinations and still say that you *ran errands*.

In *he runs to do an errand*, I would take *runs* to be literal. In other words, in order to complete his errand, he physically runs. Notice that this is different in meaning from *he ran an errand*.

In my opinion, the image includes a running person to imply that they will do the work quickly, promptly. It is does not imply that they will literally run to do the errands. Chances are they will be driving around town.

Also, *run an errand* is more common than *do an errand*: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=run_INF+an+errand%2Cdo_INF+an+errand&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t3%3B%2Crun_INF%20an%20errand%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brun%20an%20errand%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunning%20an%20errand%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bran%20an%20errand%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bruns%20an%20errand%3B%2Cc0%3B.t3%3B%2Cdo_INF%20an%20errand%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdo%20an%20errand%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdoing%20an%20errand%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdid%20an%20errand%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdone%20an%20errand%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdoes%20an%20errand%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

Comment: I think one of the more interesting facets of that Ngram is that _run an errand_ and _do an errand_ were running along neck-in-neck about [50 or 60 years ago](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=run+an+errand%2C+do+an+errand&year_start=1945&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3). Apparently, the _run_ version didn’t gain prominence (at least in writing) until the 1970s.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, **run** means *to do*, *to complete*.

However, run/ran can have many meanings.

Comment: Older answers said that already, with much more detail.